# startResolutionForResult returns an error (application crashes), GoogleApiClient connect

Tags: android, google-api-client

I've been trying to figure out how to solve this problem for a long time now, but I can't find any good information on what is going wrong.

The code originates from: http://developer.android.com/google/auth/api-client.html

So first I build the GoogleApiClient object and then onStart() try to connect it.
The connection fails and I end up inside "onConnectionFailed()"..

Here I've printed the result and this is what I get: "SIGN_IN_REQUIRED"

As that error has a solution "result.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_RESOLVE_ERROR)" will be called.

Here is where the program suddenly crashes.

Any help would be appriciated I'm quite new to android development so go easy on me!

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender.SendIntentException;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.Plus;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener  {

    /* Client used to interact with Google APIs. */
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    // Request code to use when launching the resolution activity
    private static final int REQUEST_RESOLVE_ERROR = 1001;
    // Bool to track whether the app is already resolving an error
    private boolean mResolvingError = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(Plus.API, null)
                .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        if (mResolvingError) {
            // Already attempting to resolve an error.
            return;
        } else if (result.hasResolution()) {
            Log.d("MyApp",result.toString());
            try {
                mResolvingError = true;
                result.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_RESOLVE_ERROR);
            } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                // There was an error with the resolution intent. Try again.
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        } else {
            // Show dialog using GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog()
            //showErrorDialog(result.getErrorCode());
            mResolvingError = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_RESOLVE_ERROR) {
            mResolvingError = false;
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // Make sure the app is not already connected or attempting to connect
                if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting() && !mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you print the stacktrace from `adb logcat`?

Comment: I am getting the same issue.  Getting ConnectionResult = null in onConnectionFailed() method.

Comment: PS: You don't need to call connect() again in your onConnectionSuspended method because it will automatically try to reconnect and call onConnected() if it was successfull.

Answer (score 1):

In the `onCreate` method try to:

- remove the duplicated line `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`
- remove `.addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)` or `.setScopes("PLUS_LOGIN")` as was in my case

If this does not help, try to import and run great example project from SDK samples:

```
<android-sdk-folder>/extras/google/google_play_services/
```

See https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started